# How can I pull a fork, merge changes from upstream and then push back to fork?

Tags: git, github, merge

I realize that this is a fairly documented process, but I seem to continue hitting a hiccup. I want to pull a forked project (jenkinsci/pluginname), and then merge changes from upstream (company/pluginname). The jenkins/pluginname project is a fork of ours at company/pluginname. From here I want to merge upstream/master to origin/master, and then push to origin. However, when I do this, all I get in return is git telling me that everything is up to date.

Here is what I do:

```
git clone https://github.com/jenkinsci/pluginname.git
cd pluginname
git add remote upstream https://github.com/company/pluginname.git
git fetch upstream
git checkout master
git merge upstream/master
```

From here, I just get "Already up-to-date." What I want to do next, assuming that the merge works, is simply:

```
git push origin master
```

What am I missing here?

**Update (RESOLVED)**

It turns out the diff I was looking at was from origin/master to upstream/master, not upstream/master to origin/master. Once I pushed new changes to upstream/master, the merge worked successfully. Thanks!

Comment: did you run `git fetch origin` after cloning your _fork_ ?

Comment: Bah, sorry, turns out the diff i was seeing was from origin/master to upstream/master, not upstream/master to origin/master. Once I pushed new changes to upstream/master, the merge worked successfully. Thanks!

Comment: `git add remote upstream https://github.com/company/pluginname.git`

should be:

`git remote add upstream https://github.com/company/pluginname.git`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see what you might be missing as well, it looks fine to me.
Hopefully someone else can help but just in case, maybe:

1. There really is no difference between origin/master and upstream/master?
2. Try to do `git branch -vv` just to confirm that your local master is tracking origin

Comment: To test 1, see if `git log --left-right upstream/master...origin/master` returns any commits.